Git not tracking changes after submodule deletion
Tried to use a submodule which had its own submodules, unsuccessfully, as the submodules never populated even with every manner of submodule update, sync --recursive, etc. So just removed the submodule and its associated .submodule entry, and trying to add the project as some static files from a zip in the old location. The problem is, git just seems to be entirely ignoring anything in that folder. Tried to reclone, tried stashing differences, tried deleting cache.

Edit: I needed to actually call git rm submodule-path. It errored out since the submodule was not found, but changes are now viewed anyway.

To edit your post, use the [edit] link. And don't write "edit:", we can see the edit history.
